# The connector between multiple authors

Tags: biblatex, languages, bibliographystyle, ctex

Now I need to cite Chinese and English literature meanwhile in one document. However, I can not use the proper connector between two authors according to different languages. I need to use a connector of  "和"  when I cite the Chinese literature, "and" when I cite the English literature.
For example:
汪三贵和郭子豪(2015)  ;
Kodan and Chhikara (2013)

The homologous style would also be needed in the bibliography list.

My MWE is as follow:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[hyperref,UTF8]{ctex} 
\usepackage[bibstyle=gb7714-2015,citestyle=authoryear,sorting=anyt,maxalphanames=2]{biblatex}
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}
\addbibresource{lcgxm.bib}
\begin{document}
Thanks for your help! \\ \\
\indent \textcite{Kodan2013} \\
\indent \textcite{wsggzh2015} 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Bib file is:

```
@article{wsggzh2015,
author = {汪三贵 and 郭子豪},
journal = {贵州社会科学},
number = {05},
pages = {147--150},
title = {论中国的精准扶贫},
volume = {305},
year = {2015}
} 

 @article{Kodan2013,
author = {Kodan, Anand S. and Chhikara, Kuldip S.},
journal = {Management and Labour Studies},
month = {feb},
number = {1-2},
pages = {103--133},
title = {{A Theoretical and Quantitative Analysis of Financial Inclusion and Economic Growth}},
volume = {38},
year = {2013}
}
```

Comment: Please do not post MWEs as Overleaf links: Minimise them so much that you can include them as code directly in your question. Not everyone has an Overleaf account and can access your project. Plus external links can go stale over time. Adding the code here makes sure that the question remains complete and understandable.

Comment: That said, `biblatex` does have the option to switch between languages according to the language of the work you are citing (or the surrounding language), but the standard styles do not know any Chinese. I know that there are some third-party styles about that speak Chinese, so I would look into using those: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-gb7714-2015, https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-caspervector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex` can change the citation and bibliography output according to the language of the cited work. But the standard `biblatex` styles do not have a Chinese localisation, so you cannot get Chinese output out of the box.

Since your are using a dedicated Chinese style (`biblatex-gb7714-2015`) for the bibliography anyway, I suggest you also do so for citations. Since you seem to want an author-year citation style, you should check out `style=gb7714-2015ay,`.

This will give you a comma for English works and "和" for Chinese. If English works should use "and", go for

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[hyperref,UTF8]{ctex} 
\usepackage[style=gb7714-2015ay, maxcitenames=3]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  andincite = {and},
  and       = {and},
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{wsggzh2015,
  author  = {汪三贵 and 郭子豪},
  journal = {贵州社会科学},
  number  = {05},
  pages   = {147--150},
  title   = {论中国的精准扶贫},
  volume  = {305},
  year    = {2015},
} 
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{wsggzh2015}
ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson,companion}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (汪三贵和郭子豪, 2015) ipsum (Goossens, Mittelbach, and Samarin, 1994; Sigfridsson and Ryde, 1998)]

Note that I remove the

```
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}
```

those lines interfere with `biblatex-gb7714-2015` features and the lines were ostensibly present to produce "&" before the last name, which is not what you want.